# Creating a nhibernate like query builder

Tags: c#, expression, func

I am trying to create something similar to the nhibernate fluent syntax.

I have a class called Query (where t is my class representation of a sql table) and I want to add a Where expression so that it can generate a sql string internally to be executed. I'm simply doing this for learning purposes so that is why I am not using an actual ORM. I dont need anything complex, just trying to learn the basics on how something like this is built with a Func or Expression.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

I basically want to call:

```
var query = new Query<MyDomainClass>().Where(x => x.Id == 1);
```

and have it create a query that says `"SELECT * FROM MyDomainClass WHERE Id = 1"`;

I'm not sure how to get the where part of the object working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the expression tree, see [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/mehfuzh/archive/2007/10/04/writing-custom-linq-provider.aspx) link for a quick introduction.